# No space before footnote

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I sperateley indent my footnotes in my code so it is easier for me to find them afterwards. But by doing so there is always an unwanted space between the text and the number in superscript. At the moment I just add \nospace (which isn't a command) after the text which gets rid of the space but also of course producec an error.

It looks something like this like this:

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

    \begin{document}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text\nospace
     \footnote{Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
               Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text.

    \end{document}
```

But I want it without the crutchof "\nospace".

Comment: Place a percent sign at the end of the line instead of a space or the `\nospace`. It will help ;-)

Comment: well, that was easy... =D thank you so much! =]